# Commutation relation of conjugate momentum with Laplacian of field coordinate

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, commutator

In the page 25 of the book "An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory" by Michael E. Peskin and Daniel V. Schroeder in the middle of the page the authors compute the quantity

$$ [\pi ( \textbf x',t),\frac{1}{2}\phi( \textbf x',t)(-\nabla^2+m^2)\phi( \textbf x',t)]\qquad (1)$$
where $\phi( \textbf x',t)$ and $\pi( \textbf x',t)$ are operators, with commutation relation $$ [\phi ( \textbf x,t),\pi( \textbf x',t)]=i\delta^{(3)}(\textbf x-\textbf x')$$

In the next line becomes

$$ -i\delta^{(3)}(\textbf x-\textbf x')(-\nabla^2+m^2)\phi( \textbf x',t) \qquad (2)$$

I can't understand it. How $(1)$ becomes  $(2)$?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly it should be $\pi(x,t)$ instead of $\pi(x',t)$;To derive Eq.(2) from Eq.(1), we observe that the operator $(-\nabla^2+m^2)$ does not act on $x$ but on $x'$. Therefore one can feel free to commute $\pi(x',t)$ and $(-\nabla^2+m^2)$. By doing so, one can then apply $[A,B^2]=[A,B]B+B[A,B]$ to obtain the Eq.(2).

Comment: Yes but it should be $\frac{-i}{2} \delta^{(3)}(\textbf x-\textbf x')(-\nabla^2+m^2)\phi( \textbf x',t)+\frac{-i}{2}\phi( \textbf x',t) (-\nabla^2+m^2)\delta^{(3)}(\textbf x-\textbf x') \qquad (2)$
Wright?

Comment: Yeah and then integrate by part since the expression sits in an integral; the two minus signs coming from integration by parts would cancel.